# python-vlc.. output each from dual monitors

Tags: python, vlc, multiple-monitors, python-vlc

using python-vlc in python
I want to display a video on each of the two monitors
2 videos played successfully
But only monitor 1 shows the video
Is there a way to show the video on the second monitor?

```
p1 = vlc.Instance('--directx-device=\\\\.\\DISPLAY1')
# p1 = vlc.Instance('--qt-fullscreen-screennumber=1')
media = p1.media_new("t1.mp4")
player = p1.media_player_new()
player.set_media(media)
player.video_set_scale(0.5)
player.play()

p2 = vlc.Instance('--directx-device=\\\\.\\DISPLAY2')
# p2 = vlc.Instance('--qt-fullscreen-screennumber=2')
media = p2.media_new("t2.mp4")
player2 = p2.media_player_new()
player2.set_media(media)
player2.video_set_scale(0.5)
player2.play()
```

I searched and put options in vlc.Instance, but the behavior was the same
Help me
I'm using python on windows

Comment: I succeeded by changing the argument value                                                                
playera = vlc.Instance('--video-x=10', '--video-y=10')                                                  
playera2 = vlc.Instance('--video-x=2000', '--video-y=10')

Comment: You could make this an answer, which will make it more `findable` for others with the same problem. After a day or two you can then accept that answer to this question. Welcome to SO.